# How to use socket.io in node.js with ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, websocket, socket.io

I want to make a chat application using oop architecture and javascript ES6 syntax. I don't know how to initialize socket.io. I did not find any help.

Here is my code.

```
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import config from 'config';
import SocketIO from 'socket.io'

const app = express();
const port = config.PORT;
app.set('port', port);
const server = http.createServer(app);
var io = SocketIO(server);
io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log("Socket connected");
    
});

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

I am trying to connect socket using socket-client-tool, it shows connection timeout.

Comment: I am trying to connect through socket-client-tool
https://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/

Comment: where/how are you hosting your server? maybe you're not listening to the port your cloud provider expects you to listen on?

Comment: i am currently on local host and also listening port.but nothing

Comment: I also tried it with require instead of import. Its working with require

Comment: wait, how can you use https://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/ then? are you using some tunneling tool? what exactly are you passing as "server url" in the socket-client-tool?

Comment: I just put the URL e.g "http://localhost:3000/" and press connect

Comment: I tried this many times and test many events. but now in ES6 syntax i can't connect with socket.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227338/discussion-between-tibebes-m-and-hammad-ali).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `import socketIo from 'socket.io';` did not work in my case.

I used the following method to solve this issue and to connect the socket to my already existing node express server on port 5000.

```
import cors from 'cors';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { Server } from 'socket.io'; //replaces (import socketIo from 'socket.io')

const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, { cors: { origin: '*' } });


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Connection established');
 
getApiAndEmit(socket);
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Disconnected');
  });
});


const getApiAndEmit = (socket) => {
  const response = 'response you need';
  socket.emit('FromAPI', response);
};

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);

httpServer.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  var port = httpServer.address().port;
  console.log('Running on : ', port);
});
```

And in the client, I connected as follows:

```
import React,{ useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';

const ENDPOINT = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'; //endpoint port 5000

const MyComponent = () => {

  const [response, setResponse] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
    console.log(socket);
    console.log(ENDPOINT);
    socket.on('FromAPI', (data) => {
      setResponse(data);
    });

  }, []);

     return <p>{response}</p>

}

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using it in a small project with React on the front, the server code looks like this

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import socketIo from 'socket.io';
import session from 'express-session'

var app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app)
   

// hook up session for express routes
const sessionMiddleware = session({
    // genid: req => uuidv4(),
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {}
})

// hook up the session for socket.io connections
io.use((socket, next) => sessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res || {}, next));
app.use(sessionMiddleware)


io.origins('*:*')
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    // socket.handshake.headers
    console.log(`socket.io connected: ${socket.id}`);    
    
    const { roomId } = socket.handshake.query;
    socket.join(roomId);
    
    // Leave the room if the user closes the socket
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log(`Client ${socket.id} diconnected`);
        socket.leave(roomId);
    });
});
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.io = io
    next()
})

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 4000));

server.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("App now running on port", port);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For ES6 import statement

> Without http . No need to create server with http.

I'm using it with Express + NodeJs backend only and testing it with a [website](https://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/v1/) socket io tester , the server.js code looks like this.
just paste your http://localhost:8080 and emit or listen to events.
socket.io [version 2.5.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io/v/2.5.0) is used

> ```
> import express from 'express';
> import SocketIO from 'socket.io';
> let app = express();
>
> let port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
> let server = app.listen(port, () => {
>     console.log('Listening on PORT :' + port);
> });
>
> let io = new SocketIO(server);
>
> io.on('connection', (socket) =>
>     {
>     console.log("on connection",socket.id,);
>     socket.on('ding', (ding) => {
>         console.log(ding);
>       socket.emit("update_user",{key:"value"});
>
>     });
>
>     socket.on('disconnect', () => {
>
>         console.log("disconnected");
>     });
>
>     socket.on('userChat', (data) => {
>
>         console.log(data);
>     });
> }
> );
> ```

> for socket.io >=4.x  use this syntax below

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";
const io = new Server(server);
```

Answer (score 0):

For ES6 and expressJs use the following format

```
const app = express();
const PORT = 8000;

const httpServer = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
const io = new Server(httpServer); // add after creating the http server
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried the suggested starter code block from the [official socket.io documentation](https://socket.io/get-started/chat) (see below) and it works on my end

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).